# Error trying to connect to Oracle from Rails on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

I went through all the steps described [here](http://blog.rayapps.com/2008/04/24/how-to-setup-ruby-and-new-oracle-instant-client-on-leopard/) to set up my OS X machine to allow me to connect to Oracle from a Rails app.

Set up the `database.yml` file in my app:

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: [SERVER IP ADDRESS]
  database: [ORACLE INSTANCE SID]
  username: xxx
  password: yyy
  encoding: utf8
```

Also tried it with the domain name.

Tried in Rails console...

```
>> con = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

But it hung for a long time then timed out with the error...

```
OCIError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
    from env.c:257:in oci8lib.so
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/oci8.rb:229:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:184:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:184:in `new_connection'

[...]
```

Has anyone gotten this working on OS X and knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should  have either the **host:** line or the **database:** line, but not both.

Use the **database:** line if you have a TNS entry.

```
database: orcl    ## orcl is an entry in tnsnames.ora
```

Otherwise use the **host:** format.

```
host: dbhost.example.com/orcl    # dbhost: network address of the database host
                                 # orcl: database instance name
```

More notes here:

[How to configure Ruby on Rails with Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764887/how-to-configure-ruby-on-rails-with-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

If you have sqlplus installed with your Oracle client software, you should try connecting with that first to make sure the problem is your Rails config and not your connection info or the server itself.