# How to configure Ruby on Rails with Oracle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

There's several pages on the web that discuss this, but most are out of date or inaccurate in some way.

What's the scoop?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Build ruby, gem, and rails

as per http://rubyonrails.org/download:

```
build ruby
build gem
use gem to install rails
```

### Get Oracle Instantclient

Download from 
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/downloads/index.html

You need these two packages for your architecture.

```
instantclient-basic
instantclient-sdk
```

Unzip these files, and make this link

```
cd instantclient_10_2
# .dylib for mac, .so for linux
ln -s libclntsh.dylib.10.1 libclntsh.dylib
```

### Build ruby-oci8

Note, JRuby users don't need ruby-oci8, but do need the [Oracle JDBC jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html), either ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc5.jar depending on whether you have Java 6 or Java 5.

Download from http://ruby-oci8.rubyforge.org/en/index.html and run

```
# DYLD for mac
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/instantclient_10_2
# LD for linux
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/instantclient_10_2
ruby setup.rb config
ruby setup.rb setup
ruby setup.rb install
```

Test with this line and your database connection string.

```
ruby -r oci8 -e "OCI8.new('scott/tiger@orcl').exec('select * from user_tables') do |r| puts r.join(','); end"
```

### Install activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter

Note, ***not*** **activrecord-oracle-adapter** as many older pages mention.

```
gem install activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter
```

### Do that sweet rails thing

```
rails railstest
cd railstest
# edit config/database.yml as below
ruby script/generate scaffold comic title:string issue:integer publisher:string
rake db:migrate
ruby script/server
```

### Test in browser

```
<http://localhost:3000/comics>
```

### config/database.yml

Use *database* if you have a TNS entry, otherwise use *host*.  Note that you have three entries (devel, test, production) to update.

```
development:
    adapter: oracle_enhanced
    database: orcl           # format is tns-name entry
    host:  myorclhost/orcl   # format is hostname/instance-name
    username: scott
    password: tiger
```

### References

- http://emphaticsolutions.com/2008/05/22/connecting-to-oracle-from-ruby-on-rails.html
- http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/saternos-ror-faq.html
- http://drawohara.com/post/37166893/rails-unsucking-oci-oracle-on-rails-2-1
- http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/haefel-oracle-ruby.html

Comment: When I run the "ruby -r oci8 -e..." test line, terminal shows the error: "oci8.c:654:in oci8lib_210.bundle: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (OCIError)". Any clues what I need to do?

Comment: @SeanAhrens, try the instantclient connect string format.  Here's a note on what it looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764916/oracle-what-is-the-instantclient-connection-string-format

Comment: to install ruby-oci8, come here:  https://github.com/kubo/ruby-oci8. the original link is broken.

Comment: Also, the first link is broke, to download sdk come here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

Answer (score 3):

Some additional links to previous answer.

If you are on a Mac then you can follow tutorial [How to setup Ruby and Oracle Instant Client on Mac OS X](http://blog.rayapps.com/2008/04/24/how-to-setup-ruby-and-new-oracle-instant-client-on-leopard/) to get access to Oracle database from Ruby.

Then you can read [ActiveRecord Oracle enhanced adapter wiki](http://wiki.github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced) to get Oracle connectivity in Ruby on Rails. This adapter is used in many Ruby on Rails on Oracle projects and is under active maintenance.

I also regularly post about Ruby and Oracle at my [blog](http://blog.rayapps.com).

Answer (score 3):

In my case I already had Ruby, gem, Rails and Oracle client on Windows 7. I installed ruby-oci8 binary package for Windows 32-bit:

Source: http://ruby-oci8.rubyforge.org/en/file.install-binary-package.html

```
gem install ruby-oci8
gem install --platform x86-mingw32 ruby-oci8
```

And then:

```
gem install activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter
```

and you are ready to do Rails on Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to reflect current versions (as of writing: August 2015):

- Install `libaio` (on Ubuntu/Debian Linux probably with `apt-get install libaio-dev` - 0.3.109-4)
- Download Oracle Instant Client (12.1.0.2.0, Basic + SDK should be enough, have not yet tried Basic Lite instead of Basic though)
- Set environment variables (fit to your needs):

  ```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/the/Instant/Client/directory
  export NLS_LANG="German_Germany.WE8ISO8859P1"
  ```
- Ruby (2.2.1p85), gem (2.4.6), Rails (4.2.3), ruby-oci8 (2.1.8, https://github.com/kubo/ruby-oci8) and activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.6.2, https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced) can be installed the usual way (I used `rvm` (1.26.11) for this - https://rvm.io/), so basically this should do the job for the three gems:

  ```
  gem install rails ruby-oci8 activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter
  ```
- Create your Rails app
- Configure your Rails app:

  - in `Gemfile` add `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` and `ruby-oci8`:

    ```
    gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'
    gem 'ruby-oci8'
    ```
  - in `config/database.yml` add your Oracle environment:

    ```
    development:
      adapter: oracle_enhanced
      host: my-db-host
      port: my-port
      database: my-db
      username: my-user
      password: my-password
    ```
  - Let Bundle grab the gems: `bundle install`:

    ```
    ...
    Using activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter 1.6.2
    ...
    Using ruby-oci8 2.1.8
    ...
    ```
  - Ready to rumble:

    ```
    rails generate scaffold book title:string author:string
    rake db:create db:migrate
    ...
    ```

*Note:*

Depending on your Oracle environment (i.e. `my-user` already exists or has to be created), you can omit the `db:create` statement or not. In the latter case, `rake` prompts you for the SYS/SYSTEM password in order to be able to create the user and grant it the corresponding privileges.