# Oracle: what is the "instantclient" connection string format?

Tags: oracle, connection-string, instantclient

and how does it differ from the regular connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is:

```
name/pass@//host:1521/instance
```

Standard Oracle connect strings typically look like

```
name/pass@tnsentry
```

Where `tnsentry` has been defined by one of several means such as a `tnsnames.ora` file.  idstram's answer has an excellent pointer if you're looking for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Connecting with the instant client is no different than with the full stack client - all connect string formats are the same.  If you installed the instant client in a non-standard location on the filesystem or are having problems connecting to the database listener, be sure that your TNS_ADMIN environment points to the directory that contains your tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files,

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle) is a comprehensive list of connection strings for Oracle (http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle)