# Access vba import table from Oracle via ODBC

Tags: vba, oracle, import, odbc

In Access vba, I have established a connection with Oracle database via ODBC as below.

```
Dim adConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim adRs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim myDSN As String

Set adConn = New ADODB.Connection

myDSN = "Driver=Oracle in instantclient_11_2;DBQ=111.111.111.11:1521/orcl;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True"

adConn.Open myDSN
```

And I can import table by following External data,ODBC database...  But I am not able to import table in VBA with following codes. The error message is 'failed to connect with myDSN'. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", "ODBC;DSN=myDSN", acTable, "TableName", "TableName", False
```

Comment: It says ODBC-failed to connect with "driver=Oracle in instantclient_11_2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few solutions and the script below works now.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", "ODBC;DSN=64oracle", acTable, tableName, tableName, False
```

The problem is that the string variable myDSN below is not the DSN I set up in my ODBC. The DSN should be found at ODBC setup

```
myDSN = "Driver=Oracle in instantclient_11_2;DBQ=111.111.111.11:1521/orcl;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange looking connection string, but I guess that doesn't mean it's wrong if your Server IP/Port is actually `111.111.111.11:1521` (or if you masked it intentionally!)

You can **check the setup of your Oracle [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) DSN** ([Data Source Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_source_name)) like this:

- Hit the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>Windows Key and start typing `ODBC` to open: *`Data Sources (ODBC)`*.
- Under one of the first 3 DSN tabs (User, System or File) you should have a DSN listed called `Oracle in instantclient_11_2` (based on your question).
- If it's not listed, you will need to create it.  If it *is* listed, you can double-click it and confirm the configuration.  If the UID & PW are listed there, then you **shouldn't** be specifying it in your `myDSN` string.
- Click <kbd>Test Connection</kbd> (or something similar) to test the data source.  (The exact window setup will vary depending on the company & version.)

Another troubleshooting step is to **ping the server**:

- Hit the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>Windows Key, type `cmd` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- In the Command Prompt window that opens, type `ping 111.111.111.11` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- The response should give some indication whether you can connect to the server from your machine.

Also I'm not sure that `/orcl` should be part of your `myDSN` connection string.  Where did you get that string?  Has it worked elsewhere?  Any further assistance would require more information, such as the results of these tests, and perhaps a screenshot of the ODBC DSN setup.

### More Info:

- [DSN and DBQ are Sources of Confusion When Connecting via ODBC](http://betwinx.com/Oracle8_DSN_and_DBQ.htm)
- Oracle.com : [How to Set Up a DSN on Windows](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/timesten/1121/quickstart/html/admin/dsn_setup_windows.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. As I said, ODBC was properly set up already and tested as a success to link Oracle database. In Access I could even import table by clicking 'External data '->'ODBC database'->.... But I dont know how to code this import in VBA

Comment: Alright, you hadn't mentioned that it tested successfully after you had the error.

Comment: What about my UID/PW suggestion?  Also see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42826233/8112776).