# Can Ruby on Rails connect to Oracle/RDB on Mac OS X or Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I have an older database Oracle RDB.  I used ODBC on Windows with .net, but I'm not sure how to proceed on RoR on a Mac OS X server.  I don't know how I do it on Windows either with RoR.

I was hoping for general direction.

EDIT:  I searched for activerecord and rdb but have nto found it yet.  I saw references to rdb$database and so on in code for firebird but that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How old? because there are some resources for Rails and Oracle, like this

http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/haefel-oracle-ruby.html

or maybe you could try with JRuby and JDBC, it's super easy, you have to copy the oracle jdbc jar file in the jruby/lib folder, and then in the rails project setup your database (config/database.yml) like this

```
production:
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@you_server_address:1521:instanceName
  username: user
  password: pass
```

Comment: Thank you.  I may be forced to use jRuby then (not that that's a bad thing), since there is a JDBC driver or Oracle RDB.  If I do this do I still get all the "regular" ActiveRecord and RoR stuff?

Comment: absolutely! JRuby is an implementation of the Ruby language, so rails runs fine without any modification!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Oracle Rdb specific JDBC driver. Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/rdb/index-090638.html

Answer (score 0):

This question shows how to configure RoR with Oracle on linux and mac:

- [How to configure Ruby on Rails with Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764887/how-to-configure-ruby-on-rails-with-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle RDB is different from Oracle RDBMS

Comment: yes.  it is different.  RDB was Digital's (I think) long ago, now owned by Oracle.