# Rails + Oracle + oracle_enchanced adapter: db:create asks for SYSTEM password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord

I just updated an [older post about Rails + Oracle DB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/764887/1099385) and wondered why my `rake db:create db:migrate` asks me for the SYS/SYSTEM password of the Oracle DB. The Oracle user I have configured at `config/database.yml` has these permissions:

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO my-user;
GRANT ALTER SESSION TO my-user;
GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO my-user;
GRANT CREATE SYNONYM TO my-user;
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO my-user;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO my-user;
GRANT GATHER_SYSTEM_STATISTICS TO my-user;
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO my-user;
GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO my-user;
GRANT CREATE DATABASE LINK TO my-user;
GRANT CREATE TYPE TO my-user;
```

This is what Rails is prompting me for:

```
Please provide the SYSTEM password for your Oracle installation (set ORACLE_SYSTEM_PASSWORD to avoid this prompt)
```

I do not understand why, as `my-user` should have all permissions needed for its own schema.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that requiring SYSTEM password for `rake db:create` is hardcoded in the gem.

```
def create
  system_password = ENV.fetch('ORACLE_SYSTEM_PASSWORD') {
    print "Please provide the SYSTEM password for your Oracle installation (set ORACLE_SYSTEM_PASSWORD to avoid this prompt)\n>"
    $stdin.gets.strip
  }
  establish_connection(@config.merge('username' => 'SYSTEM', 'password' => system_password))
  begin
    connection.execute "CREATE USER #{@config['username']} IDENTIFIED BY #{@config['password']}"
  rescue => e
    if e.message =~ /ORA-01920/ # user name conflicts with another user or role name
      connection.execute "ALTER USER #{@config['username']} IDENTIFIED BY #{@config['password']}"
    else
      raise e
    end
  end
  connection.execute "GRANT unlimited tablespace TO #{@config['username']}"
  connection.execute "GRANT create session TO #{@config['username']}"
  connection.execute "GRANT create table TO #{@config['username']}"
  connection.execute "GRANT create view TO #{@config['username']}"
  connection.execute "GRANT create sequence TO #{@config['username']}"
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/d22964ed051d491b128e8554720f2c681474b793/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_tasks.rb)

As you can see, it also actually `creates` the user which you set in your `database.yml` and gives some privileges to it.

It's probably the best to skip `rake db:create`. You can always create database manually once in production environment, and in development/testing environment it's alright to give SYSTEM access to your Ruby code.

Comment: Oh yeah, shame on me ... I could have looked up the source code myself ... :-/

Ok, but with these GRANTS, CREATE USER that makes absolutely sense.