# How to connect a rails app to a oracle database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord, rails-activerecord, sequel

I am unable to find step by step instructions on this topic. I want a Rails 5.x app to be able to connect to an Oracle Database.

I know that there are adapters out there, but I want to start from a default Rails 5 app and connect to a Oracle Database and query the database.

If there is not a viable ActiveRecord way, I will accept a Sequel (the ruby ORM Gem) based answer.

Please explain each step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at "[Ruby on Rails on Oracle: A Simple Tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/haefel-oracle-ruby-089811.html) or "[How to configure Ruby on Rails with Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764887/how-to-configure-ruby-on-rails-with-oracle)".