# Active Record - Changing from mysql to oracle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to rails. We have a application that is running using MySQL database in production. All the seeds job and model are present. Now I need to change to Oracle. I changed the connection adapter to point to Oracle. What are all the other changes required.Do I have to change the model. For authentication and users , we are taking from database using devise gem. So what changes required

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how `devise` gem fits into the whole equation as I have not used it. But I have had to set up a ruby on rails project to work with Oracle database. It involved installing the Ruby/Oracle Call Interface library.

There are several questions on the same that have been answered. Here's a link to one of them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31783055/4054389

good luck.

Comment: I am using Oracle adapter too to connect to external database.Application uses MySQL db for loading users, encrypted password etc .It has sessions and version table too. Do I have to create seasions table too in oracle