# How do I configure Rails and SQLPlus on Oracle VM to work together

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, oracle, macos, ora-12170

For one of my projects I need to use an Oracle database on a Rails app.

For my local development, I've installed [Oracle VM VirtualBox](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html) with the package [Oracle Developer Day](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html) .
I successfully deployed, launched the VM, logged in and even created a user on SQLPlus with admin rights.

On my mac OSX Mavericks, I've installed [instant client from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html) as well as the following version of ruby-oci8 and activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter

```
   gem ruby-oci8', '~> 2.0.6'
   gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.4.1'
```

My config file for my dev database is the following database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: 192.168.2.170:1521/myprogram_development
  username: my_new_sql_plus_username
  password: my_new_sql_plus_password
```

On Oracle VM side, I've set up my network as the screenshot shows

[image: Network NAT]
[image: Forwarding ports]

When I connect my VM I have the same IP as the database.yml file above

[image]

All that looks fine (I've followed every steps of [this tutorial](http://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/how-to-install-oracle-database-on-mac-os-any-version/) and also tried [this one](http://www.jeffmdean.com/2012/3/13/developing-locally-with-oracle-and-ruby-on-a-mac) ), but when I try my `rake db:setup` command or to access the db via `OCI8.new("my_new_sql_plus_username", "my_new_sql_plus_password", "//192.168.2.170:1521:1521/orcl")`, I have the following error message.

```
rake aborted!
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
oci8.c:267:in oci8lib_191.bundle
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:326:in `new'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:326:in `new_connection'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:436:in `initialize'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:24:in `new'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:24:in `initialize'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_connection.rb:9:in `new'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_connection.rb:9:in `create'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_base_ext.rb:13:in `oracle_enhanced_connection'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced.rake:26:in `create_database_with_oracle_enhanced'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `each'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/stephanethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => db:create
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Use just the database as listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758771/error-trying-to-connect-to-oracle-from-rails-on-os-x

Comment: I tried that already, unsuccessfully unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. So couple of problems:
First the network config. Use Bridged adapter instead of NAT, like below

[image]

Second, the config file in the rails app (database.yml), don't forget the 2 slashes in front of the IP ...

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: //192.168.2.170:1521/myprogram_development
  username: my_new_sql_plus_username
  password: my_new_sql_plus_password
```

And it's all good !